I am trying to adjust sticky positioning for my header dynamically with JS. How can I achieve this?
This is my first personal project and I am having trouble dynamically altering the sticky positioning on my header with JS. All I want to do is to remove the sticky positioning I have set on the head class after I have scrolled past the bottom of the intro class. How do I achieve this using JavaScript?
This is the html code I have for the header and intro sections.
<header id="head">
        <div class="title">
            <h1 style="font-size: 2.5rem; margin-left: 10px;">
                Health & Wellness
            </h1>
            <img src="C:\Tech Stack\Website Design\CSS Practicee\Images\download (2).png" style="height: 60px; width: 100px; border: none; object-fit: cover;">
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="search"><i class="bi bi-search" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>Search</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="home">Home</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="about">About</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" id="services" style="color: white">Services</button>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="intro" id="intro">
        <h2>Health & Wellness Blog Articles</h2>
        <p>Read posts from experts at Harvard Health Publishing covering a variety of health topics and perspectives on medical news.
        </p>
    </div>

Here is the CSS
#head{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #CDFFFC;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 15px;
    
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #CDFFFC;

And here is the Javascript


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    
    const header = document.getElementById('head');
    const introSection = document.getElementById ('intro');

    // Calculate the bottom position of the intro section

    const introBottom = introSection.offsetTop + introSection.offsetHeight;

    if(window.scrollY >= introBottom) {
        header.classList.remove('sticky');
    }else {
        header.classList.add('sticky');
    }
});


Simply wrap the header and the intro into the same container. A sticky element will always remain a child element of its container. As such it will leave the screen as soon as the parent element leaves it.
No JS required:


header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}


main {
  min-height: 500vh;
}
<div>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div id="intro">
    <p>Intro</p>
    <p>Intro</p>
    <p>Intro</p>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <p>Further Content</p>
</main>



